# UITableView calling deleteRow() method crashed by missing placeholder for index path

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

Here's my code for editing tableView:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
        plistContentArray = readFile()
        let section : NSInteger = indexPath.section
        let row : NSInteger = indexPath.row
        var sectionDictionary:NSMutableDictionary = plistContentArray.object(at: section) as! NSMutableDictionary
        var contentArray = sectionDictionary.object(forKey: "Content")
        if contentArray is String {
            print("String")
            plistContentArray.removeObject(at: section)
            plistContentArray.write(toFile: plistPath, atomically: true)
            let sectionPosition = section
            let sectionIndexSet = IndexSet(integer: sectionPosition)
            self.tableView.deleteSections(sectionIndexSet, with: .fade)

        } else {
            let valueToDelete = (contentArray as! NSArray).object(at: row) as! String
            let originalValue = contentArray as! [String]
            let filteredValue = originalValue.filter{ $0 != valueToDelete }
            sectionDictionary.setValue(filteredValue, forKey: "Content")
            plistContentArray[section] = sectionDictionary
            print(plistContentArray)
            plistContentArray.write(toFile: plistPath, atomically: true)

            let sectionPosition = section
            let sectionIndexSet = IndexSet(integer: sectionPosition)
            if filteredValue.count == 0 {
                plistContentArray.removeObject(at: section)
                plistContentArray.write(toFile: plistPath, atomically: true)

                self.tableView.deleteSections(sectionIndexSet, with: .fade)

            } else {
                tableView.beginUpdates()
                let indexPathToDelete = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
                self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPathToDelete], with: .automatic)
                tableView.endUpdates()

            }
        }

    }
}
```

readFile() method is a method I use to get data from plist file.
And the application crashed when delete row 1 (section 2) at "tableView.deleteRows()"
Console:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView internal inconsistency: missing placeholder context for this index path: <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000200216> {length = 2, path = 2 - 1}'
```

[Deleting Row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwWW1.png)

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: i think you don't have a section 2

Comment: **Never** use `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift. You cannot cast objects to `NSMutable...` classes (not even in Objective-C). You'll never get a mutable object. Other very bad *objectice-c-ish* code is `NSInteger`, `value(forKey / setValue(forKey` and writing `NS...` Foundation collection types as property list to disk. Don't do that in Swift. There is `Int`, key subscription and dedicated API `PropertyListSerialization` to serialize property lists. And `beginUpdates / endUpdates` has no effect at all for a single insert/delete/move operation.